# CSqlDataProvider attributeLabels

Tags: php, yii

```
<?php
//form
class SomeForm extends CFormModel
{
    public $id;
    public $user_id;

    public function search()
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT id, name FROM some_table';
        $sql_count = 'SELECT COUNT(id) FROM some_table';
        return new CSqlDataProvider($sql, array(
            'totalItemCount' => Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql_count)->queryScalar(),                                    
            'sort' => array(
                'attributes' => array(
                    'id', 'name',
                ),                
            ),
            'pagination' => array(
                'pageSize' => 50,
            ),
        ));
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'name' => 'NAME',            
        );
    }
}

//grid
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(), //$model = new SomeForm()    
    'columns' => array(
        'id',
        'name'
    ),
));
/*
Result:
id | name
---------
1  | John

EXPECTED Result:
ID | NAME
---------
1  | John
*/
```

How to set custom names for query columns ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(), //$model = new SomeForm()    
    'columns' => array(
        'id::ID',
        'name::NAME'
    ),
));
```

Another way:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(), //$model = new SomeForm()    
    'columns' => array(
        array(
            'header' => 'ID',
            'name' => 'id'
        ),
        array(
            'header' => 'NAME',
            'name' => 'name',
        ),
    ),
));
```

[Link to api doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#columns-detail)

Comment: Another option: `'header' => $model->getAttributeLabel('id'),`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use custom names; if you want to use your labels declared in your model, then you can do this:

1. Create an empty instance of your model and pass it to your view. The view will thus utilize the `$data` (`CSqlDataProvider`) as well as the empty model.

   ```
   $labelModel = new my_model;

   $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView',array(
       'dataProvider'=>$my_model->search(), //returns a CSqlDataProvider
       'itemView'=> '_view',
       'viewData' => array('labelModel' => $labelModel),
   ));
   ```
2. Use the empty model - together with getAttributeLabel - to echo labels.
3. Use `$data['field_name']` to echo the data.

This [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/252/special-variables-in-cgridview-and-clistview/) has more info on how to pass the additional model to the `CListView` or `CGridView`.